# Why can't I add a developer to a facebook app?

Tags: facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps, roles

My client has reached their friends limit and so I cannot become a friend.
In the developer section under roles:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps/[longId]/roles

I want to add myself as a developer.
It appears that the field is checking against existing friends as I type.
When I finish adding my email it says I am not a facebook user. Not True.

Has any one run into this?
It appears that I need to be a friend to test on the app.

Comment: Did you try adding them via the API? see the `roles` connection of the Application object

Comment: Do you mean adding the developer email via an api call or adding a friend?

Comment: API: adding them to a role using the application edit API

Comment: can you point me to some documentation on how to do that?

Comment: curl --data "user=nmericId&role=developers&access_token=thetoken" https://graph.facebook.com/appId/roles

Comment: Thanks Igy:  http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/application/#roles

Comment: Still need to unfreind someone so I can be added as a developer. I am now in the pending list which looks like it still depends on the friends limit. I think this is a stupid facebook feature that only facebook friends can develop your app

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can input user ID in those fields.